# Forward a port outside a VPN network

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

I'm dealing with a scenario involving 3 devices: 1) A VM (Ubuntu), 2) a laptop (Win11), 3) a desktop (Arch)

- The VM runs in a separate network protected by a VPN.
- I can access the network from the laptop via this VPN connection.
- I'd like a service running on the VM to be visible to my desktop machine which doesn't (can't) have access to the VPN.
- The laptop and desktop are on the same LAN, which is distinct from the LAN running the VM

Is there a (relatively) simple setup I can use to *expose* this service to my desktop such that I can access it as though it's running in the desktop's network, rather than the isolated one?

I'm experimenting with port-forwarding which for question's sake we'll use the service port 8080. This however, doesn't seem to get me very far as the VPN connection seems to break down every time I attempt to forward ports to various places.

The other option is for me to of course connect the desktop to the VPN directly, but there are several reasons I'd prefer to avoid that, amongst which is that the desktop itself is running network services which my home-setup depends on.

I'm hoping for suggestions on how this might be achievable.
Please let me know if more context is needed here.

Cheers

Comment: Does the VPN allow split tunnel?

Comment: yes it does. However, the laptop should still be able to access the service as well